# FeedbackPanel with link

Tags: java, wicket

Is there any solution for build a Feedback Panel that contains inside messages with Link? I try to use this:

```
            StringBuilder stringBuilder= new StringBuilder(512);
            stringBuilder.append("<a href=\"");
            stringBuilder.append(Utils.getAbsoluteUrl(EditBookingSourcePage.class, new PageParameters())+"");
            stringBuilder.append("\">Clicca Qui!</a>");

            feedbackErrorPanel.info(stringBuilder);

public static <C extends Page> String getAbsoluteUrl(final Class<C> pageClass, final PageParameters parameters) {

    CharSequence resetUrl = RequestCycle.get().urlFor(pageClass, parameters);
    String abs = RequestUtils.toAbsolutePath("/", resetUrl.toString());
    final Url url = Url.parse(abs);
    return RequestCycle.get().getUrlRenderer().renderFullUrl(url);
}
```

but doesn't work.

Comment: "doesn't work" doesn't explain much what doesn't work. Please give more information which part exactly does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @martin-g mentioned first you should escape the html tag. `feedbackPanel.setEscapeModelStrings(false)`

As you mentioned you did. I believe url construct issue . So whatever you have done on Top of that Try below step. I have tried below solution it worked for me .

```
     //since you are not passing any parameter we can send null
    String absoluteUrl = RequestCycle.get().getUrlRenderer().renderFullUrl(
                            Url.parse(urlFor(EditBookingSourcePage.class, null).toString())); 


StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                stringBuilder.append("<a href=");
                stringBuilder.append(absoluteUrl);
                stringBuilder.append("\">Clicca Qui!</a>");
          feedbackErrorPanel.info(stringBuilder);
```

In WicketApplication page

```
mountPage("setting/booking-source", EditBookingSourcePage.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to call `feedbackPanel.setEscapeModelStrings(false)`.
Without this Wicket will escape all HTML characters to prevent XSS attack.

Comment: The problem is that the method urlFor() doesn't work always in the same way. I have mount the page under the path "/setting/booking-source" and one time urlFor return back the correct path, while other times urlFor return back the incorrect path (like "/booking-source")

Comment: The url is relative to the url of the current page. If the current page is `/setting/something-else` then the relative will be `./booking-source`, note the leading dot!

Answer (score 0):

Another apporach is to:

1, extend org.apache.wicket.markup.html.panel.FeedbackPanel

2, extend org.apache.wicket.feedback.FeedbackMessage and store data

3, Create MyMessagePanel with its own markup, model object

4, override newMessageDisplayComponent method in extended FeedbackPanel

```
@Override
    protected Component newMessageDisplayComponent(String id, FeedbackMessage message) {
        //message with its own markup
        if (message.getClass().equals(MyMessage.class)) {
            MyMessage msg = (MyMessage) message;
            return new MyMessagePanel(id, Model.of(new MyMessagePanelModelObject(msg.getModelObject()))); //my message markup
        }

        return super.newMessageDisplayComponent(id, message); //other messages
    }
```